# How to clear the 'igdkmd32.sys' blue screen error on win 8.1

Tags: windows-8

I've recently upgraded my computer to Win 8.1. There is now a blue screen problem whenever the system 'wakes up' from sleep mode. It happens every time, accompanying with the message about 'igdkmd32.sys' error.

does anyone have such experience?

(note, i am running the windows system through iMac bootcamp setup)

Comment: Welcome to superuser!  My understanding is that before you post here, you should make an attempt to research your problem, and include any attempted resolutions in your post. If it will help, the blue screen is about the Intel Graphics Kernel Mode Driver -- so you may want to check re. your display driver, roll back, or see what other actions have worked for others.

Comment: Intel Graphics Accelerator Driver V10.18.10.3262 should support Windows 8.1

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick replies. that might be a direction to have a look.

Comment: First try to update or reinstall your drivers, the 8.1 upgrade messes up with drivers from what I've seen.

Comment: I've installed the latest version AMD Radeon HD 6700M driver(Catalyst manager) for my iMac, but it didn't help.

Comment: Update: the problem has mysteriously gone. i didn't do any changes or updates.